# How to turn '\n Simon Smith\n ' to 'Simon Smith' in python

Tags: python-3.x

'\n      Simon Smith\n    ' to 'Simon Smith' in pythonWhat's the easiest way to turn '\n      Simon Smith\n    ' to 'Simon Smith' in python.

Is there a function to clean things like white spaces, \n and other things?

Answer (score 0):

```
string = '\n Simon Smith\n '
print(string.replace("\n", "").strip())
```

**NOTE**: `replace()` is not really necessary here. It's just added as a way to show how it works.

The `strip()` method removes the beginning/ending spaces in string.

> string.strip(s[, chars])¶ Return a copy of the string with leading and
>   trailing characters removed. If chars is omitted or None, whitespace
>   characters are removed. If given and not None, chars must be a string;
>   the characters in the string will be stripped from the both ends of
>   the string this method is called on.

Changed in version 2.2.3: The chars parameter was added. The chars parameter cannot be passed in earlier 2.2 versions.

The `replace()` method, replaces the first characters with the second.

> string.replace(s, old, new[, maxreplace]) Return a copy of string s
>   with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional
>   argument maxreplace is given, the first maxreplace occurrences are
>   replaced.

[Documentation reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to remove all leading and trailing whitespace from the string:

```
import re

t = '\n Simon Smith\n '
print('*' + t + '*')
t = re.sub(r'(^\s+|\s+$)', '', t)
print('*' + t + '*')
```

Output

```
*
 Simon Smith
 *
*Simon Smith*
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

```
>>> x = '\n Simon Smith\n '
>>> x.strip()
'Simon Smith'
```